# SQLite работа со строкой

Tags: sqlite3, sql

Добрый день. У меня есть табличка, в ней колонка с таким форматом строки ( ip[/folder] )

```
12.12.12.12[/folder]
12.34.56.78[/otherFolder]
11.11.11.11[/folder3]
```

Необходимо составить запрос, что бы выдало 2 колонки (ip , /folder). То есть разрезать строку и отбросить символы квадратных скобок. Все это необходимо сделать на SQLite.
Спасибо за участие и ответы

Comment: @QuitLN, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: Вопрос, а нафига это надо? Почему если надо удалить гланды, так обязательно через анус?

Comment: Ответ - из-за производительности. В моем проекте используется самописанный язык программирования. И объемы базы - большие. Поэтому разрезать ее при получении - будет слишком затратной операцией. Идея в том, что бы нагрузить SQLite, который оптимизирован под большие объемы данных. И брать инфу из базы сразу готовую.

Comment: @QuitLN Если эти данные в столбце используются как два разных поля, то почему не изменить схему базы данных, разбив их загодя на два столбца?

Comment: Уже есть большой объем такой информации с которой приходится работать. Такой формат - последствие неверно принятого решения на этапе создания структуры. Вносить изменения уже поздно. Приходится работать с тем, что есть.
Вопрос встает не о выполнении работы. А о вспомогательных функциях. Есть ли в SQLite хотя бы способ получить номер позиции символа '[' в строке ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite не имеет встроенных функций для разбивки строк по разделителю. Что можно сделать?

1. Заменить знак "/"на определенное количество пробелов функцией replace.
2. Разбить строку на две по максимальной длине левой части с учетом пробелов функцией substr.
3. Удалить ненужные пробелы функцией trim.
4. Удалить квадратные скобки функцией substr или replace.

То есть сделать так:

> `1.2.3.4/[xyz]       - исходная
> 1.2.3.4         [xyz] - с пробелами
> 1.2.3.4         , [xyz] - разбита на части
> 1.2.3.4, [xyz]          - без пробелов
> 1.2.3.4, xyz            - без скобок`

Другой вариант - это написать самому расширение SQLite на C.

Answer (score 1):

Надо разрезать строку одним из методов указанных [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql), затем заменить символы квадратных скобок на пустые символы и еще обернуть все это дело на `TRIM()`

P.S. Сидеть за вас писать никто не будет - это точно

**Update** Поскольку SQLite это embedded БД, то скорее всего все это безобразие происходит либо под Android либо под iOS, так что лучше все таки получить полную строку, потом средствами Java или Objective C нормально разрезать, чем действительно удалять гланды через анус (как было отмечено камрадами в каментах)